# Magento 1.5 install on Mac OSX - Errors on Installer

Tags: magento, installation, mamp

I'm trying to install Magento 1.5 Community Edition on Mac OSX. I'm using MAMP Pro to redirect the url test.com to run a specific Magento 1.5 folder.

I get a set of error messages before I even begin the install process. Can anyone help decipher?

There has been an error processing your request

```
SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'andrey_konosov_build'

Trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(251): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Type/Db/Pdo/Mysql.php(45): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Type_Db_Pdo_Mysql->getConnection(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_read')
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(312): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->_getConnection('read')
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Cache.php(41): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(434): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Cache->getAllOptions()
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(469): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1137): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(412): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#14 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#15 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(395): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#16 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(329): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#17 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento15/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to install the latest RC1 release candidate?  I just downloaded it myself, and it looks like their build process (accidentally?) left this information in.  The `local.xml` file is where Magento keeps come configuration information, such as the username and password to use for a database.  In previous version of the system, it shipped **without** a `local.xml`.  This file was created during the installation process.

My guess is, as mentioned, the file was included accidentally.  I'd try renaming it to something else, or removing it from the folder, and starting your installation.  If that doesn't work, then I'd just enter your mysql DB information in `local.xml` to work  around the problem

Worth reporting as a bug

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking

Comment: FYI: I removed the shipping local.xml and was able to install the latest version without issue.

Comment: When I removed the local.xml from the etc folder the install didn't work.

Comment: Ah, mainly asked for those who came later. Hearing that,  I bet Magento had cached the contents of local.xml.  You probably could have removed the file, and then deleted var/cache, and run the installer.  If that doesn't work, grep/ack your codebase for the "andrey_konosov_build" string.  Magento has to be picking it up from somewhere!

Answer (score 2):

My name is Dmitriy, i'm technical project manager of Magento Core Team. 1.5.0.0-rc1 packages were wrongly packaged and contains local.xml file from test installation. Please remove local.xml file from app/etc folder or download package one more time. We have fixed packages. Sorry for this issue but like you know the old saying sais "He is lifeless that is faultless".

Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

```
Access denied for user ''@'localhost'...
```

You are missing a username.

**Edit:**
Look in the `/app/etc/` directory for both `local.xml` and `config.xml`. Either of those might already have database details set in advance which would derail the installation process.

Comment: Yes - local.xml has db details already inserted. Do you suggest removing those ?

Comment: <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[andrey_konosov]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[andrey_konosov_build]]></dbname>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please remove local.xml comming from downloaded archive. It's definety bug.